# Send adb command using PERL

Tags: android, perl

Lets take a simple example.
My android real device is connected to PC via USB and ADB is connected.

I used

```
 D:\Test>adb shell input keyevent 29
```

to enter A

I want to implement a PERL script for this and want to execute same functionality using

```
C:\Perl\bin>perl t.pl
```

I tried:
t.pl  content:

```
 system("adb shell input keyevent 29");
```

It say adb is not recognized command

Comment: Did you configure **adb** under *environment variables* ?

Answer (score 1):

**The code you have written should work, unless your ADB is configured in environment variable.** Try the script using your android device id.

Once you configure the environment variable of ADB, do this.

D:\Test>adb devices

Once you get the device ID, try the following code in your perl script.

```
system("adb -s <device id> shell input keyevent 10");
```

**P.S:** I tried with **10 keyevent** using *dialer* to check which key press in number 10. It presses *number 3* from the dialpad.